# Can't display contents of a DataTable in a Datagridview in C#

Tags: c#-2.0

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    public class Example
    {
        private void CreateTable()
        {

            //create datatable instance
            DataTable myTable = new DataTable();

            //create columns
            DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn("A");
            DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn("B");
            DataColumn col3 = new DataColumn("C");

            //define datacolumn data types
            col1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int");
            col2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            col3.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");

            //add columns to table
            myTable.Columns.Add(col1);
            myTable.Columns.Add(col2);
            myTable.Columns.Add(col3);

            //create row in table
            DataRow row = myTable.NewRow();

            //populate columns with data
            row[col1] = "1001";
            row[col2] = "ABC";
            row[col3] = "HIJ";

            //add rows to table
            myTable.Rows.Add(row);


        }


    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Completely off-topic, but row[col1] is a string when you populate, but its data type is an int.

Answer (score 1):

You were not calling the `CreateDataTable()` method or the dataGridView1.DataBind() method. I modified your example to return the `DataTable` type from the CreateTable method.

```
    private DataTable CreateTable()
    {

        //create datatable instance
        DataTable myTable = new DataTable();

        //create columns
        DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn("A");
        DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn("B");
        DataColumn col3 = new DataColumn("C");

        //define datacolumn data types
        col1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int");
        col2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        col3.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");

        //add columns to table
        myTable.Columns.Add(col1);
        myTable.Columns.Add(col2);
        myTable.Columns.Add(col3);

        //create row in table
        DataRow row = myTable.NewRow();

        //populate columns with data
        row[col1] = "1001";
        row[col2] = "ABC";
        row[col3] = "HIJ";

        //add rows to table
        myTable.Rows.Add(row);

        return myTable;
    }

}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = CreateTable();
    dataGridView1.DataBind();
}
```